# Playing mp3 files from thread in android

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I've just created Thread object in Java with run method inside. I thought it would be possible to create `MediaPlayer` object here and play some songs in mp3 format from **Android directory**: `/data/data/application/files`. My goal is to play one song after another. Each for specified time period (like 20 seconds).
However it's not clear to my how to create `MediaPlayer` object (what should I pass as `context`?)

Moreover I don't know how to play one song for specified period of time and then change to next one.

Maybe `MediaPlayer` is not suited for such task? I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have this code for an alarm

```
private void playSound(Context context, Uri alert, Boolean alarm) {

    try {

        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0
                && alarm == true) {
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            alarmisplaying = true;
        } else {

            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            alarmisplaying = false;

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("OOPS");
    }
```

as context you can pass getApplicationContext() and if you want to stop playing just pass false as alarm(pass true if you start to play the sound).

Answer (score 1):

You can find much of the basics in this [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html). The context is an object you need quite often in Android applications, usually it is the Activity or the Service that is active at the moment and that signifies your connection to the Android framework.